# Making Jquery slideshow automatically play?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

Ok, so I can't find anything on here that has worked for me. Perhaps I'm placing it in the code wrong since I've only just started using jQuery. I'm assuming you use 'true' somehow, but I just don't understand it. Here's my code:

```
        <div id="slider" class="sl-slider-wrapper">

            <div class="sl-slider">

                <div class="sl-slide" data-orientation="horizontal" data-slice1-rotation="-25" data-slice2-rotation="-25" data-slice1-scale="2" data-slice2-scale="2">
                    <div class="sl-slide-inner">
                        <div class="bg-img bg-img-1"></div>
                        <h2>Sabina Apartments</h2>
                        <blockquote><p>Luxury fully appointed one bedroom apartments.</cite></blockquote>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="sl-slide" data-orientation="vertical" data-slice1-rotation="10" data-slice2-rotation="-15" data-slice1-scale="1.5" data-slice2-scale="1.5">
                    <div class="sl-slide-inner">
                        <div class="bg-img bg-img-2"></div>
                        <h2>Sabina Apartments</h2>
                        <blockquote><p>Upstairs apartments feature vaulted ceilings and a sunny outlook.</cite></blockquote>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="sl-slide" data-orientation="horizontal" data-slice1-rotation="3" data-slice2-rotation="3" data-slice1-scale="2" data-slice2-scale="1">
                    <div class="sl-slide-inner">
                        <div class="bg-img bg-img-3"></div>
                        <h2>Sabina Apartments</h2>
                        <blockquote><p>Built using natural materials including concrete, schist facings, steel and double glazed argon filled glass. </cite></blockquote>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="sl-slide" data-orientation="vertical" data-slice1-rotation="-5" data-slice2-rotation="25" data-slice1-scale="2" data-slice2-scale="1">
                    <div class="sl-slide-inner">
                        <div class="bg-img bg-img-4"></div>
                        <h2>Sabina Apartments</h2>
                        <blockquote><p>Kitchens feature stone bench tops, quality stainless steel appliances including tall dish drawer, fan forced oven, ice and water dispensing fridge/freezer.</cite></blockquote>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="sl-slide" data-orientation="horizontal" data-slice1-rotation="-5" data-slice2-rotation="10" data-slice1-scale="2" data-slice2-scale="1">
                    <div class="sl-slide-inner">
                        <div class="bg-img bg-img-5"></div>
                        <h2>Sabina Apartments</h2>
                        <blockquote><p>Quality soft furnishings and floor coverings provide a warm and luxurious environment, even through Dunedin's chilly winters.</cite></blockquote>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /sl-slider -->

            <nav id="nav-dots" class="nav-dots">
                <span class="nav-dot-current"></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </nav>

        </div><!-- /slider-wrapper -->

        <div class="content-wrapper">

        </div>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="FullscreenSlitSlider/js/jquery.ba-cond.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="FullscreenSlitSlider/js/jquery.slitslider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(function() {

            var Page = (function() {

                var $nav = $( '#nav-dots > span' ),
                    slitslider = $( '#slider' ).slitslider( {
                        onBeforeChange : function( slide, pos ) {

                            $nav.removeClass( 'nav-dot-current' );
                            $nav.eq( pos ).addClass( 'nav-dot-current' );

                        }
                    } ),

                    init = function() {

                        initEvents();

                    },
                    initEvents = function() {

                        $nav.each( function( i ) {

                            $( this ).on( 'click', function( event ) {

                                var $dot = $( this );

                                if( !slitslider.isActive() ) {

                                    $nav.removeClass( 'nav-dot-current' );
                                    $dot.addClass( 'nav-dot-current' );

                                }

                                slitslider.jump( i + 1 );
                                return false;


                            } );

                        } );

                    };

                    return { init : init };

            })();

            Page.init();
```

Many thanks

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. Narrow your code down to show the specific problem. Explain exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The problem your code you forgot import script modernizr.custom.79639.js

Here is edit you code

```
<div id="slider" class="sl-slider-wrapper">

            <div class="sl-slider">

                <div class="sl-slide" data-orientation="horizontal" data-slice1-rotation="-25" data-slice2-rotation="-25" data-slice1-scale="2" data-slice2-scale="2">
                    <div class="sl-slide-inner">
                        <div class="bg-img bg-img-1"></div>
                        <h2>Sabina Apartments</h2>
                        <blockquote><p>Luxury fully appointed one bedroom apartments.</cite></blockquote>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="sl-slide" data-orientation="vertical" data-slice1-rotation="10" data-slice2-rotation="-15" data-slice1-scale="1.5" data-slice2-scale="1.5">
                    <div class="sl-slide-inner">
                        <div class="bg-img bg-img-2"></div>
                        <h2>Sabina Apartments</h2>
                        <blockquote><p>Upstairs apartments feature vaulted ceilings and a sunny outlook.</cite></blockquote>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="sl-slide" data-orientation="horizontal" data-slice1-rotation="3" data-slice2-rotation="3" data-slice1-scale="2" data-slice2-scale="1">
                    <div class="sl-slide-inner">
                        <div class="bg-img bg-img-3"></div>
                        <h2>Sabina Apartments</h2>
                        <blockquote><p>Built using natural materials including concrete, schist facings, steel and double glazed argon filled glass. </cite></blockquote>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="sl-slide" data-orientation="vertical" data-slice1-rotation="-5" data-slice2-rotation="25" data-slice1-scale="2" data-slice2-scale="1">
                    <div class="sl-slide-inner">
                        <div class="bg-img bg-img-4"></div>
                        <h2>Sabina Apartments</h2>
                        <blockquote><p>Kitchens feature stone bench tops, quality stainless steel appliances including tall dish drawer, fan forced oven, ice and water dispensing fridge/freezer.</cite></blockquote>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="sl-slide" data-orientation="horizontal" data-slice1-rotation="-5" data-slice2-rotation="10" data-slice1-scale="2" data-slice2-scale="1">
                    <div class="sl-slide-inner">
                        <div class="bg-img bg-img-5"></div>
                        <h2>Sabina Apartments</h2>
                        <blockquote><p>Quality soft furnishings and floor coverings provide a warm and luxurious environment, even through Dunedin's chilly winters.</cite></blockquote>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /sl-slider -->

            <nav id="nav-dots" class="nav-dots">
                <span class="nav-dot-current"></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </nav>

        </div><!-- /slider-wrapper -->

        <div class="content-wrapper">

        </div>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlitSlider/js/modernizr.custom.79639.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlitSlider/js/jquery.ba-cond.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlitSlider/js/jquery.slitslider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
       $(function() {

                var Page = (function() {

                    var $navArrows = $( '#nav-arrows' ),
                        $nav = $( '#nav-dots > span' ),
                        slitslider = $( '#slider' ).slitslider( {
                            onBeforeChange : function( slide, pos ) {

                                $nav.removeClass( 'nav-dot-current' );
                                $nav.eq( pos ).addClass( 'nav-dot-current' );

                            }
                        } ),

                        init = function() {

                            initEvents();

                        },
                        initEvents = function() {

                            // add navigation events
                            $navArrows.children( ':last' ).on( 'click', function() {

                                slitslider.next();
                                return false;

                            } );

                            $navArrows.children( ':first' ).on( 'click', function() {

                                slitslider.previous();
                                return false;

                            } );

                            $nav.each( function( i ) {

                                $( this ).on( 'click', function( event ) {

                                    var $dot = $( this );

                                    if( !slitslider.isActive() ) {

                                        $nav.removeClass( 'nav-dot-current' );
                                        $dot.addClass( 'nav-dot-current' );

                                    }

                                    slitslider.jump( i + 1 );
                                    return false;

                                } );

                            } );

                        };

                        return { init : init };

                })();

                Page.init();

                /**
                 * Notes: 
                 * 
                 * example how to add items:
                 */

                /*

                var $items  = $('<div class="sl-slide sl-slide-color-2" data-orientation="horizontal" data-slice1-rotation="-5" data-slice2-rotation="10" data-slice1-scale="2" data-slice2-scale="1"><div class="sl-slide-inner bg-1"><div class="sl-deco" data-icon="t"></div><h2>some text</h2><blockquote><p>bla bla</p><cite>Margi Clarke</cite></blockquote></div></div>');

                // call the plugin's add method
                ss.add($items);

                */

            });
            </script>
```

Working demo : http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlitSlider/